# How to read a file into a dictionary, where key is the word and value is the number of repeating words in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, text-files

Say i have a text file that says:

```
hello yellow apple yellow apple apple yellow....
```

How would i change this to a dictionary so it says the word then number of times it repeats:

```
{"hello": 1, "apple": 3, "yellow": 2}
```

I am new to python and having trouble figuring this out, the text file is large so i will need to make one dictionary over multiple lines.

Comment: Could you show your best attempt, and explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
letters = 'hello yellow apple yellow apple apple yellow'
data = {}
for word in letters.split(' '):
    if word in data:
        data[word] += 1
    else:
        data[word] = 1

print(data)
```

With the output being

```
{'apple': 3, 'yellow': 3, 'hello': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

[File reading](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), [text splitting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split), and [counting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) are all concepts that you should read up on in some tutorial and try for yourself first before just asking for a solution. Once you do that you will find this is a concise way to solve this:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  c = Counter(f.read().split())  // c is a dict-like object holding the counts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_string="hello yellow apple yellow apple apple yellow".split(" ")
results={}
for i in list_string:
    results[i]=list_string.count(i) if i not in results else results[i]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading in a file of words, this should do it:

```
# Open your file of words and read it.
with open('my_file', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

# Replace newline characters with spaces and remove any
# spaces at the end of the string of words.
data = data.replace('\n', ' ').rstrip()

# Create a list out of the string, split on the space
# character.
words = data.split(' ')

result = {}
for w in words:
    if w not in result:
        result[w] = 1
    else:
        result[w] += 1

print result
```